# Is it possible to create another DatastoreV1.Read inside a currently executing pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I know it is possible to create two queries at the beginning using PCollections, KVs, and CoGbkResult, but you must specify your DatastoreIO.Reads outside of the ParDos/DoFns. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    PubsubIO.Read.Bound<String> pubsub = PubsubIO.Read.named("ReadFromPubsub")
            .subscription(subscriptionPath);

    pipeline.apply(pubsub).apply("Query DB with UserId" , ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            String userId = c.element().toString();

            //Query database using userId....
        }
    }));

    pipeline.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can put any arbitrary code that you like inside a `ParDo` and it will be executed with any problems. However, bear in mind that your code will be running inside the Dataflow distributed environment, so you cannot share state, depend on ordering etc.

Comment: Could you provide a example of querying the database from inside the ParDo?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do with the query. But it's straight forward. Just use the client lib, and call the API. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial

Comment: Have a look here where I call the Natural Language API from inside my `ParDo`. It's the same principle. https://shinesolutions.com/2016/12/20/analysing-stack-overflow-comment-sentiment-using-google-cloud-platform/